# Wordpress renames slug of tags used in multiple taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, tags

I've noticed Wordpress renames the slug of identical tags used across multiple taxonomies, is there an easy way to change this behavior?

Let's say I create a tag called Nintendo under the publisher taxonomy, then also create a Nintendo tag under the developer taxonomy. Wordpress will prefix the slug of the second tag with a 2.

This basically makes the taxonomy/tag system unusable for my application. I want the slugs to stay the same across multiple taxonomies.

Answer (score 2):

Found out why, slug column has a UNIQUE index. Looks like I'm just going to have to code my own script to handle the publisher/developer relations if I want a consistent URL structure. Thought WP was more flexible than this, oh well :/

Comment: See http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22023 – this is planned for the near future. You could help with unit tests. :)